# Menu bar is not visible when the screen is made smaller

Tags: html, css

I was trying to write the header of the page with a video as background. The navigation links are available when the screen is above 1200px. But the menu bar is not visible when the screen is made smaller than 1200px. How to fix the invisible menu bar?

This is the html code which includes the video as background and the related navigation links. The menu bars and times icons are also inserted.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2% 6%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav img {
  width: 140px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-links {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

.nav-links ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-links ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.header video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

nav .fa {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .nav-links ul li {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 10px;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    right: -200px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 1s;
  }
  nav .fa {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="header">
  <video src="images/Helicopters9.mp4" muted loop autoplay></video>
  <nav>
    <a href="Home.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="helicopter" /></a>
    <div class="nav-links" id="navlinks">
      <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="HOME.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="FAQs.html">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="MemberArea.html">MEMBER AREA</a></li>
        <li><a href="CommunityGroup.html">COMMUNITY GROUP</a></li>
        <li><a href="PlacesToFly.html">LATEST PLACES TO FLY</a></li>
        <li><a href="TrainingOnline.html">TRANING ONLINE</a></li>
        <li><a href="Review.html">REVIEW</a></li>
      </ul>
      <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
    </div>
  </nav>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `menu` is visible on smaller than `1200ox` screens too. Just change the `background-color` of link such that white color is visible on it or change `color` other than white.

On smaller screen a scroll bar is created and your `menu` aligns to the right-most part of screen

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2% 6%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav img {
  width: 140px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-links {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

.nav-links ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-links ul li a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.header video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

nav .fa {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .nav-links ul li {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 10px;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    right: -200px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 1s;
  }
  nav .fa {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="header">
  <video src="images/Helicopters9.mp4" muted loop autoplay></video>
  <nav>
    <a href="Home.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="helicopter" /></a>
    <div class="nav-links" id="navlinks">
      <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="HOME.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="FAQs.html">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="MemberArea.html">MEMBER AREA</a></li>
        <li><a href="CommunityGroup.html">COMMUNITY GROUP</a></li>
        <li><a href="PlacesToFly.html">LATEST PLACES TO FLY</a></li>
        <li><a href="TrainingOnline.html">TRANING ONLINE</a></li>
        <li><a href="Review.html">REVIEW</a></li>
      </ul>
      <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
    </div>
  </nav>
</section>
```

Comment: It doesn't work out. The background is the video so the menu bar icon should be visible even though it is white.  The icons are not displayed when the site is in full screen. When the screen is below 1200px, the icons should be displayed as in written in @media.

Comment: Scroll to the right you will find your menu icon in above snippet @Meranda . It may be that you video don't span below all the icons in small screen . Try to change color and scroll to the right